# Select query using key firebase admin node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I've a table like this in firebase:

```
thread_users{
  thread_id{
    user_id{
      //user details
    }
  }
}
```

`thread_users` should have multiple `thread_id`s and each `thread_id` has multiple users.

I only have the `user_id` of a user. I need to query using this `user_id` to find  `thread_id`s of the user has belonged.

I haven't found any good solution for this requirement. Kindly help me to do this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to save your `user_id` to `thread_id` mappings separately. This will denormalize some of the data, but this is perfectly normal and even [recommended](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure) when working with the Firebase realtime database.

Alternatively you can look into [Cloud Firestore for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model). There you should be able to create a document per `thread_id`, and have a subcollection of `users` in each document.